# Is there an open data api or service for dates of official government holidays?

Tags: api, calendar

Is there a service or Open API that exists out there for providing the dates of existing holidays in the US including observed holidays?

Unfortunately, from my google searches I've just found a paid service [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/holiday-api.html) and [bank-holidays.com](http://www.bank-holidays.com/) from this particular [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203708/is-there-a-comprehensive-api-or-json-xml-list-with-public-bank-holidays-worldwid).

I intend to just build my own event calendar application for self learning.

Comment: It seems that the old easy URL http://opm.gov/fedhol (federal holidays) now sends you to 'archive.opm.gov' with a message that it's no longer being maintained.  The new location official location seems to be http://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/ and for next year, http://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/#url=2014

Comment: And although not an official 'federal' holiday, DC's Emancipation Day is April 16th.  (which can affect tax day, as it's never on a Sunday, but it can't be on April 16th, either ... so if April 15th is a Sunday, then the tax deadline is moved to April 17th, not April 16th)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system for (US) federal holidays is rather simple. As described in [5 USC 6103](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/6103), it's basically just a short list of specific dates and rules for weekends.

This could certainly be integrated into your calendar but you might want to find a more complicated data source to practice with an API. To keep on the same theme, how about religious holidays? ([example](http://www.hebcal.com/home/195/jewish-calendar-rest-api))

Answer (score 0):

There is the free https://date.nager.at/ service. I found it useful for some projects, although I had to "borrow" some dates from Liechtenstein and Germany when working on requirements for an Austrian customer.

Unfortunately I have been looking here for a more complete service which includes some other dates like school holidays. For Germany we have https://ferien-api.de/. The bank-holidays offering comes close and adds a bit more which would be nice for travel plans, but so far, just for querying a few dates with curl once a month for private use, the pricing and usage restrictions appear prohibitive to me.